# Как добавить элемент в многоуровневый массив python

Tags: python

У нас имеется многоуровневый массив

```
cars = [["Ford", "Volvo", "BMW"],
        ["Mercedes", "Audi", "Toyota"]]
```

Как с помощью метода `insert()` добавить новый элемент во второй массив, чтобы получилось

```
        ...
        ["Mercedes", "Audi", "Honda", "Toyota"]]
```

Comment: Ну так cars[1].insert

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!